# Migrating RxSwift to Combine

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, combine

I'm migrating from RxSwift to Combine and ran into this issue related to error handling:

```
func myMethod(firstName: String?) -> Observable<Data> {
     guard let firstName = firstName else {
     return Observable.error(MyErrorEnum.error)
    }
    return someAPICall... 
}
```

I'm migrating to Combine as follows:

```
func myMethod(firstName: String?) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
     guard let firstName = firstName else {
     // can't quite figure out how to return an error here... 
    }
    return someAPICall... 
}
```

I normally don't struggle handling errors, specially when working with network calls, but for some reason this one is avoiding me.

Really appreciate any input!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail)?

Comment: I have tried that but get "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: I am suspecting the issue is with your API call and especially the type of error your API call expects (I assume `URLError`s). If that is the case, you either make `Fail` return the same error type or 'generify' the error using your custom struct (i.e. add another case `urlError(URLError)` and map the error

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Fail` publisher:

```swift
func myMethod(firstName: String?) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
    guard let firstName = firstName else {
        return Fail<Data, Error>(error: MyErrorEnum.error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    return someAPICall... 
}
```

But I'd argue that your design is the optimal one, you'd better simply require a non-optional `firstName` and make the callers aware that your method doesn't work well with nil values.

Comment: I agree and tried getting rid of the optional(s), but it seems to create a bigger problem because my method is called in multiple places across the app. For some reason though I Publishers has no "Fail". Publisher, on the other hand, has Failure but Xcode complains about "Associated type 'Failure' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base". Gotta find a way around that

Comment: @JadielAlfonso yes, you'd have to unwrap the value before passing it to `myMethod` in multiple places, but at the same time you'll have to deal with the error corresponding to the nil value, so I'd say the gain is not big.

Comment: You say that getting rid of the optional String is painful, but I notice you aren't checking for an empty String. Is it really OK for someone to have "" as a name? Something to think about... If there is no logical difference between an empty container and a `nil` then why have the nil and be forced to check for both?

Comment: Also, I found `Fail` not in the `Publishers` namespace... `return Fail(error: MyErrorEnum.error).eraseToAnyPublisher()` worked fine for me.

Comment: @DanielT., yes, `Fail` is not in the `Publishers` namespace, corrected the answer, thanks.